# Class variable is causing segfault

Tags: c++

I am using a class that someone else created in my group, and I noticed reduceStamina is giving a segfault. Anytime _staminaBar is used the program just segfaults. I also tried getting the name of the actor, and that also caused a seg fault. The first thing I checked was if the default constructor was being called, it was not called. (I used to have a cout in the default constructor) Then I checked if the variable was initialized in the other constructors, and it was.

Why is _reduceStamina causing a segfault?
My program makes it to "In reduceStamina"

```
#ifndef ACTOR_H_
#define ACTOR_H_

#include <iostream>
#include "../resources/vector3d.h"
using namespace std;

namespace bammm
{
    class Actor
    {

        private:
            float _rotation;
            string _name;
            Vector3D *velocity;
            Vector3D *location;

            int _healthBar;
            int _staminaBar;
            int MAX_HEALTH;
            int MAX_STAMINA;

            int _attack;
            int _defense;

        public:
            //Constructors
            Actor();
            Actor(string myName);
            Actor(string myName,int health,int stamina,int atck, int def);

            //Functions
            /*
                setRotation
                @Pre-Condition- takes no arguments
                @Post-Condition- returns rotation
            */
            void setRotation(float myRotation);
            /*
                setName
                @Pre-Condition- takes no arguments
                @Post-Condition- returns name
            */
            void setName(string myName);
            /*
                increaseHealth
                @Pre-Condition- Takes an float amount 
                @Post-Condition- Increases health by said amount
            */
            void increaseHealth(int amount);
            /*
                increaseStamina
                @Pre-Condition- Takes an float amount 
                @Post-Condition- Increases stamina by said amount
            */
            void increaseStamina(int amount);
            /*
                reduceHealth
                @Pre-Condition- Takes an float amount 
                @Post-Condition- Decreases health by said amount
            */
            void reduceHealth(int amount);
            /*
                reduceHealth
                @Pre-Condition- Takes an float amount 
                @Post-Condition- Decreases stamina by said amount
            */
            void reduceStamina(int amount);
            /*
                isFullyRested
                @Pre-Condition- no parameters
                @Post-Condition- returns true if healthBar and staminaBar are equal to                              MAX_HEALTH and MAX_STAMINA
                                 returns false otherwise;
             */
            bool isFullyRested();

            inline float getRotation()
            {
                return _rotation;
            }

            inline string getName()
            {
                return _name;
            }

            inline string getVelocity()
            {
                return velocity->toString();
            }

            inline string getLocation()
            {
                return location->toString();
            }

            inline int getHealth()
            {
                return _healthBar;
            }

            inline int getStamina()
            {
                return _staminaBar;
            }

            inline int getAttack()
            {
                return _attack;
            }

            inline int getDefense()
            {
                return _defense;
            }



    };

    Actor::Actor()
    {
    }

    Actor::Actor(string myName)
    {
        _name = myName;
        _rotation = 0;
        velocity = new Vector3D();
        location = new Vector3D();

        MAX_HEALTH = 100;
        MAX_STAMINA = 50;
        _healthBar = MAX_HEALTH;
        _staminaBar = MAX_STAMINA;
        _healthBar = 100;
        _staminaBar = 50;
        _attack = 4;
        _defense = 2;
    }

    Actor::Actor(string myName,int health,int stamina,int atck, int def)
    {
        _name = myName;
        _rotation = 0;
        velocity = new Vector3D();
        location = new Vector3D();

        MAX_HEALTH = health;
        MAX_STAMINA = stamina;
        _healthBar = MAX_HEALTH;
        _staminaBar = MAX_STAMINA;
        _healthBar = health;
        _staminaBar = stamina;
        _attack = atck;
        _defense = def;
    }

    void Actor::setRotation(float myRotation)
    {
        _rotation = myRotation;
    }


    void Actor::setName(string myName)
    {
        _name = myName;
    }


    void Actor::increaseHealth(int amount)
    {
        if (_healthBar>=MAX_HEALTH)
        {
            _healthBar = MAX_HEALTH;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            _healthBar += amount;
        }
    }


    void Actor::increaseStamina(int amount)
    {
        if (_staminaBar>=MAX_STAMINA)
        {
            _staminaBar = MAX_STAMINA;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            _staminaBar += amount;
        }
    }


    void Actor::reduceHealth(int amount)
    {
        if (_healthBar > 0)
        {
            _healthBar -= amount;
        }
        else
        {
            _healthBar = 0;
            return;
        }
    }


    void Actor::reduceStamina(int amount)
    {
        cout << "In reduceStamina" << "\n";
        cout << "_stamina: " << _staminaBar << "\n";
        if (_staminaBar > 0)
        {
            _staminaBar -= amount;
        }
        else
        {
            _staminaBar = 0;
        }
    }


    bool Actor::isFullyRested()
    {
        if (_healthBar == MAX_HEALTH && _staminaBar == MAX_STAMINA)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
#endif
```

Comment: How are you instantiating your Actor?

Comment: It's being instantiated with Actor::Actor(string myName)

Comment: Why are you using pointers to allocate the vectors?

Comment: There is no reason to allocate dynamically that things at all. I'm pretty sure the segfault is relationed with your way to allocate objects.

Comment: "I am using a class that someone else created in my group". It was the creator's design decision. Why would that have anything to do with _staminaBar causing a crash?

Comment: Then someone should have tought him better. He does not respect the rule of three (or five in C++11). This means that those vectors are only shallow copied when the object is copied which can lead to serious problems.

Comment: Thank you, I will let him know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the crash is not visible in your code sample. What's presumably happening is that the function is being called on a non existing object.

Consider this code:

```
int foo;
Actor * bad_actor = 0;  // No Actor object exists, only a null pointer.
bad_actor->reduceStamina(4);
```

That will fail in a way like you're seeing. Probably the cause isn't quite so simple to see like here, but you need to look at the backtrace of what's calling the reduceStamina method, because it doesn't have a valid Actor object.

Comment: If the actor is invalid it will still go into the function?

Comment: This was the problem, thank you. I'm surprised a NULL object will still call its methods.

Comment: @user1932934 Yeah, the object isn't tested before calling methods on it to avoid impacting execution speed.